# NativeScript - TimePicker Cannot get user modified value

Tags: angularjs, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am unable to get the user modified value of a TimePicker. All I'm getting is the original value that I set in the control.

Here is my component template:

```
<TabView [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex" selectedColor="#FF0000" style="height:90%">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Time'}">
        <TimePicker #timePicker [(ngModel)]='model.time'></TimePicker>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Date'}">
        <DatePicker #datePicker [(ngModel)]='model.date'></DatePicker>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
<button text="Done" (tap)="onDoneTap()"></button>
```

And my component code:

```
export class DateTimePickerComponent 
{
    public mDate: Date;
    public tabSelectedIndex: number;
    public model: any;

    constructor() 
    {
        this.mDate = new Date();
        this.model = {
            date: new Date(2014, 5, 13, 2, 24),
            time: new Date(2014, 5, 13, 2, 24)
        };
    }

    private onDoneTap()
    {
        this.mDate.setMinutes(this.model.time.getMinutes());
        this.mDate.setHours(this.model.time.getHours());

        this.mDate.setDate(this.model.date.getDate());
        this.mDate.setMonth(this.model.date.getMonth());
        this.mDate.setFullYear(this.model.date.getFullYear());  

        console.log(this.mDate);   
    }
}
```

To build this I used the [Docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/angular-data-binding):

- DatePicker - date property
- TimePicker - time property

In This example the DatePicker works perfectly, it initialise at 2014-05-13 and when I change it, I get the modified value in the console. So am I doing something wrong with the TimePicker ?

Note: I also tried to read the hour and minute property using the ID without success. Always the same initial value (2:24)

```
@ViewChild("timePicker") timePicker: ElementRef;
let datePickerView = <TimePicker>this.timePicker.nativeElement;
console.log(datePickerView.hour);  //  2
console.log(datePickerView.minute) // 24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might fall here:

A bug was opened on Github for this issue. [[see here]](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2940).

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be caused when you missed to add `NativeScriptFormsModule` in `imports` in your `main.ts` file. You could review the given example below:

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic, NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [NativeScriptModule, NativeScriptFormsModule],
})
class AppComponentModule {}
```

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppComponentModule);

I hope this helps.

Update:
You could return the `TimePicker` value as an argument for your `onDoneTap`method. You could review the attached example.

app.component.html

```
<StackLayout  exampleTitle toggleNavButton>
<!-- >> creating-timepicker-html -->
<timePicker class="example-container" #timePicker  verticalAlignment="center"></timePicker>
<!-- << creating-timepicker-html -->
<Button text="view" (tap)="ontap(timePicker.time)"></Button>

</StackLayout>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    public ontap(args:Date){
        console.log(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea but no, I do have "NativeScriptFormsModule" in my imports

Comment: Did you try add `NativeScriptFormsModule` in your `main.ts` file to verify whether this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I updated my project with your update suggestion and I'm getting "undefined" in args...

Comment: I found that the problem is that the `Button` is outside the `TabView` and the it is not possible to find the id for the inner component. To be able to to get timePicker value, you should move  `Button` inside the `TabView` Items, for your could move it inside the StackLayout.

Comment: You were right with the button not being close enough, now I get a time output in the console. Unfortunately, it still shows 2:24 and not what I am selecting in the TimePicker

Comment: I didn't have time to work on this until now, and I realize I didn't specify that I'm using the timepicker in clock mode which seem to be the problem. when I change it back to spinner it works. I'll open an issue on Github. I totally overlooked this